# Failed to setup Alerts and Actions for ELK - You must enable Transport Layer Security

Tags: elasticsearch, action, alert, kibana-7, elasticsearch-x-pack

Am trying to setup the Alert and Actions for ELK. But, getting the error message

- You must enable Transport Layer Security.

Have already set up the following parameter in the kibana.yml. As followed:

xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"

Pls advise.

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHnsk.png)

Answer (score 0):

> xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"

With only this, you don't enable the transport layer security.

There are two more steps you need to do.

1. [Enable security in Kibana and Elasticsearch.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/using-kibana-with-security.html) (Relatively easy!)
2. [Encrypt traffic between them](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/configuring-tls.html#configuring-tls-kib-es). (You might need to get your org-specific certificates if you are not using Self signed1)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the basic and trial licenses ,
Set **xpack.security.enabled: true** and **discovery.type: single-node** in elasticsearch.yml file

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/get-started-enable-security.html

and then **xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey : A string of 32 or more characters** in kibana.yml

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.16/alert-action-settings-kb.html#general-alert-action-settings

After updating the config file please restart the elastic and kibana .